# Seven balls are to be distributed randomly into seven cells. Let X4= # of cells containing exactly 4 balls.

Tags: probability

Seven balls are to be distributed randomly into seven cells.  Let  X4= # of cells containing exactly 4 balls.Determine the probability distribution of X4.

Is finding probability distribution is same as finding probability?
If it is, my work;
This can be done in the following ways; (4,3,0), (4,2,1), (4,1,1,1)

For example, the probability of happening (4,1,1,1)=

We can choose the cell that contains 4 balls in 7C1=7 ways.
We can choose 4 distinguishable balls from 7 balls= 7C4 
The 5th ball can be assigned to 6 different cells= 6C1
The 6th ball can be assigned to 5 different cells= 5C1
The 7th ball can be assigned to 4 different cells= 4C1
Also the last three balls can be distributed in 3! ways.

And our sample space is= 7.7.7.7.7.7.7= 7^7

So we multiply all these and repeat the process for the other ways. Is there anything wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the probability distribution of $X_4$ means to find the probability that $X_4=0$, the probability that $X_4=1$, the probability that $X_4=2$, and so on.

1) Since there are only $7$ balls, $P(X_4\ge 2)=0$.

2) $P(X_4=1)$ is the sum of the probabilities of three scenarios you mentioned. You are on the right track to calculate it.

3) $P(X_4=0) = 1- P(X_4=1)$, which you get from (2).

Comment: Then why sample space in the below link is n^n.      https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476114/probability-of-n-balls-in-n-cells-one-remaining-empty     isn't that also supposed to be n! ?

Comment: Nevermind, that was my mistake. I was thinking of identical balls. Fixed the answer.

Comment: No really, I also think it has to be n!. I still don't get why it has to be n^n. Because once you put a ball in one of the cells regardless it is identical or not, it is gone, now you have n-1 balls. iSn't that so? What am I missing?

Comment: If the balls are distinguishable, the first one can be placed in any of the 7 cells in 7 ways. Then the second ball can be placed in any of the 7 cells, and so on.

Comment: First equation should be a strict inequality. Otherwise the second equation is also trivially equal zero, which would not be correct, as you can have a four-ball cell.